# copy by value an array and all its elements

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to copy an array and all its elements, but I'm not getting it.

I have a model with name, and options, both strings

this is what I have:

```
const myArrayToCopy = [myModel, myModel, myModel]
```

What I do to copy is:

```
const copy = Object.assign([],myArrayToCopy);
console.log(copy === myArrayToCopy) //false
console.log(copy[0] === myArrayToCopy[0]) //true -> bad
```

then I tried

```
copy[0] = Object.assign(myArrayToCopy[0]) 
//still true
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You need to use `Object.assign()` like this: `copy[0] = Object.assign({}, myArrayToCopy[0]) `

Comment: this is not the same, because instead of myModel, I got {name:'a', options:'b'}

Comment: Equality is one of the most initially confusing aspects of JavaScript. The behavior of == versus ===, the order of type coercions, etc. all serve to complicate the subject. Today we'll be looking at another facet: how object equality works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a deep copy, such as provided by `lodash`:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
let copy_array = _.cloneDeep( myArrayToCopy);
```

The convenience is that it generalises to any depth.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be

```
const copy = myArrayToCopy.map(o => ({...o}))

copy === myArrayToCopy // false
copy[0] === myArrayToCopy[0] // false
```

Answer (score 0):

`let myCopy = myArrayToCopy.map((elem) => Object.assign({}, elem));`

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), Object.assign is copying all properties from the second arguments into the first one.

As pointed out by Learning a mess, this solution doesn't work with complex objects (i.e nested objects).

Comment: this doesn't work because I don't have this kind of object, I have one based on model

Comment: I truly don't understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all the possibilities

```js
const myArrayToCopy = [myModel, myModel, myModel];
const sameMemReference = myArrayToCopy; // Same memory reference
const newMemReference = [...myArrayToCopy]; // Different memory reference, but same for the objects
const  totalMemDifference = [...myArrayToCopy.map(obj => ({...obj}))]; // total memory difference
```

To sum up :

- change `sameMemReference` your first array changes.
- change `newMemReference`, you array doesn't change

  - change the objects in it, the objects in your first array change
- change what you want in `totalMemDifference`, it won't affect your first array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify for deep copy of object.

```
let a = { x:{z:1} , y: 2};
let b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
```

Comment: this doesn't work because I don't have this kind of object, I have one based on model

Answer (score 0):

For deep copy, you can do this :

```
copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myArrayToCopy))
```

Comment: this doesn't work because I don't have this kind of object, I have one based on model

Comment: On whatever model your data is based on, it will be a JS object, and it will work with that.

Comment: no, it creates a {name:name, options:options} insetead an object of class "myModel"